# How to create new columns with the average monthly , quaterly withdrawal amounts for individual account no using panda?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

[image]

```
data.groupby(['Account No']).agg({ "WITHDRAWAL AMT": ["count", "sum"], "DEPOSIT AMT":["count", "sum"],
                                            "BALANCE AMT": ["count", "sum"]})
```

giving the result for individual user but not able to do in monthly basis.

```
data.groupby(['Account No']).agg({ "WITHDRAWAL AMT": ["count", "sum"], "DEPOSIT AMT":["count", "sum"],
                                            "BALANCE AMT": ["count", "sum"]})
```

There should be only one row for an individual user.

Comment: Welcome to SO; please spend a minute to see how to properly format your code blocks; Also, this is a standard `pandas` question, and has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: Could you add desired Outputs? Question is unclear.

Comment: columns should be: Account No, quarterly average of withdrawal amount (difrent columns with different quarterly average like q1,q2....)

Comment: The question is still not specific enough. Could you provide sample input and output for one column related to [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways, from which I'll suggest two

Firstly:
add a grouper, i.e. modify your groupby to

```
df.groupby(["Account No", pd.Grouper(key="Date", freq="M")]
```

Secondly:
Create a year and month column from date, and groupby those. Change your grouby to:

```
df.assign(Year=lambda x: x["Date"].dt.year, Month=lambda x: x["Date"].dt.month)
  .groupby(["Account No", "Year", "Month"])
```

same is possible with quarters.

Now after you have grouped the data, you can use [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html#pandas.DataFrame.unstack) to move the grouper objects to the columns, creating one row per user.

You need to do the same with quarters and then merge/concat the data frames. So it will be a multi-step approach.

Comment: its grouping by date. I wanted to create columns with the quarterly or monthly counts like below:   Account No (column name): a , 1st quarter average amount(column name): 1500

Comment: This does not really help. I added some comments on how to flatten the results. But you need to be more specific in your questions